# How to split a long speech in Alexa Amazon

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a simple "skill" in Alexa where I ask her questions and the answers are "hardcode" in the code since they are fixed answers.

One of the Intents is activated with the phrase "Tell me the 9 rules of ...". The problem is that these rules are very long and the user can get bored quickly.

I want that Alexa tells me rules 1, 2 and 3, and asks, "do you want to continue listening?" If you say:

- yes, she tells me the following three rules, and so on.
- no, she goes back to the initial menu, the "Skill Invocation".

It is possible to do that?.

Here is the piece of code of that Intent that I have right now:

```
class TheNineRulesIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
"""Handler for TheNineRulesIntent."""
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
    return ask_utils.is_intent_name("TheNineRulesIntent")(handler_input)

def handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
    speak_output = 
      "The Nine Rules are:\
    1. Long Text...\
    2. Long Text...\
    3. Long Text...\
    4. Long Text...\
    5. Long Text...\
    6. Long Text...\
    7. Long Text...\
    8. Long Text...\
    9. Long Text... "

    return (
        handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speak_output)
            .ask(speak_output)
            .response
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can play with SSML where you can easily define the way how text is spoken by Alexa.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is just remember how many rules Alexa has already spoken (using [Session Attriubutes](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html). Just every time user asks about the rules build the response using not-long-too-much amount of rules and question about further listening.